# MongoDB $where recursion

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

I want to use recursion in $where expression, but code below does not work. Where am I wrong?
Thanks! )

```
$code = new MongoCode('

function foo(bar) {
   if (bar.catId == 100) {
      return true;
   } else {
     if (bar.child) {
        foo(bar.child);
     }
   }

}

foo(this);

');

$result = $db->categories->find(
    array(
        '$where' => $code
    )
)->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to use this sort of [server-side code execution](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution); evaluation of the JavaScript `$where` clause is a serious performance blocker.

You should instead use the built-in operators, where possible.

In this case, an [$or](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or) would be more suitable:

```
$result = $db->categories->find(
    array('$or' => array(
            array("catId" => 100),
            array("child.catId" => 100)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I have unlimited nested level (

Comment: @VadimKasich: You will probably need a more efficient document structure.  The MongoDB documentation has a helpful page on [Trees in MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB).